# Add space between two elements on the same line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am adding two element on the row

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Icon
         name='person' 
         color='#98999c'
         onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this)} /> 
         <Text style={ styles.header }>
          { 'User Name' }
        </Text>
          
      </View>
          )
  }
```

How can I add a space between them?

EDIT:

I also have the same problem here:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppDrawer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft:
       <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <Icon name="menu" size={35} margin={30} padding={30} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />
      <ChangeLanguage style={{ margin: 30 , padding: 30}} />
      </View>,
      headerRight: 
      <HeaderUserInformation />,
    })
  }
```

Comment: use padding / margin ?

Comment: Or render a `{" "}` between the two elements?

Comment: @linasmnew dose not work in the second example

Comment: You only added the second example 30 minutes after I answered the original question... it seems to be a custom component are you sure that it takes style as a prop?

Comment: add {" "} where you want to space between two words

Answer (score 54):

You can use curly braces like an expression with both double quotes and single quotes for space i.e.,

```
{" "} or {' '}
```

You can also use ES6 template literals i.e.,

```
`   <li></li>` or `  ${value}`
```

You can also use &nbsp like below

```
<span>sample text &nbsp; <span>
```

You can also use &nbsp in dangerouslySetInnerHTML when printing html content

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'sample html text: &nbsp;'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks, Template literals worked for me even directly like  {`2020  •  Documentary  •  Biography`}

Answer (score 9):

Option 1:

- add: `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the `View`

Option 2:

- add `padding` / `margin` to either your `Icon` or your `Text` components

Comment: It worked for me for the first example, but not for the second. The ChangeLanguage component position dose not change.

Comment: The second example that you just edited in  seems to be a custom component are you sure that it takes style as a prop?

Comment: Spaces between inline elements are needed for wrapping. For example `<span>a..a</span><span>b..b</span>` will not be wrapped, however `<span>a..a</span> <span>b..b</span>` will be properly wrapped. In normal HTML we generally put them onto different lines and get the proper behaviour without thinking about it. React however joins elements together without adding whitespaces, so it has to be done explicitly using `{" "}`.

Answer (score 5):

I quite like using the [short syntax for fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax):

```
<><strong>Foo</strong> </>
```